# Set multiple cursor values in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an IMG element c.  The following works to change its cursor (in Chrome):

```
c.style.cursor='-webkit-zoom-out';
```

But if I try to add compatibility for other browsers, as in the following, it breaks:

```
c.style.cursor='-webkit-zoom-out, -moz-zoom-out';
```

(And I haven't even gotten to trying to link a .cur for IE-compatibility....)  What's the correct syntax to add multiple values to a style element?

Comment: Do you need to do this with javascript? This is a CSS3 style, so you are targeting modern browsers. I don't know your use case, but you might be able to apply it with CSS and get your desired effect.

Comment: You should be setting the cursor via CSS, toggle a class or attribute, and let CSS handle the styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add them separately:

```
c.style.cursor = '-webkit-zoom-out';
c.style.cursor = '-moz-zoom-out';
```

Unfortunately `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` are not supported by Internet Explorer yet. See the [MDN Cursor: Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor#Browser_compatibility).

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/MaDnM/)

**Alternatively** you can create a CSS class that sets the correct styles and add or remove this class using JavaScript if you need to toggle it.

Comment: Weird -- so `=` in javascript is sometimes actually `+=`?  How can one tell when, and how can one clear a property with this characteristic (since presumably `.cursor = '';` would not remove previous values)?

Comment: Actually it doesn't concat it. It works the same way as if it were a CSS rule. The browser picks the value he can process and discards any other. If you inspect the element in the demo, you'll see, that only `-webkit` or `-moz` is applied as an inline style. The same as a CSS rule it would be: `img { cursor: -webkit-zoom-out; cursor: -moz-zoom-out; }` instead of `img { cursor: -webkit-zoom-out, -moz-zoom-out; }`. See this other [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cV3VN/).

Comment: Thank You! Here is part of working example (XSLT, but idea is same):               <a onmouseover="javascript:this.style.cursor='pointer';javascript:this.style.cursor='hand';" onclick="openCqwpInDialog('{$SafeLinkUrl}')"  title="{@LinkToolTip}">